# Is there an English translation of Ladislaus Bortkiewicz’s book “The Law of Small Numbers" (1898)?

Tags: references, rare-events

I finished reading [*Deaths by horsekick in the Prussian army – and other ‘Never Events’ in large organisations*](https://associationofanaesthetists-publications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/anae.13261). It led me down a rabbit hole of thinking about Poisson point processes modelling demand on healthcare services that ended with: "I would like to read Bortkiewicz’s book".

Unfortunately I don't see a reasonable quality English translation. Via a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/rx4yqo/q_english_translation_of_ladislaus_bortkiewiczs/) I found this [low-quality translation](https://archive-org.translate.goog/stream/dasgesetzderklei00bortrich/dasgesetzderklei00bortrich_djvu.txt?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) by Google Translate, but I would rather not read it.

Comment: Otherwise... It wouldn't kill me to learn some more German. It is just a large investment of time added on top of my other duties.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I'm glad you found the FYI irrelevant. I've found there is some risk of people focusing on the background info' rather than the main question (perhaps thinking that there is an XY problem).

Comment: FWIW, the first edition is available at https://eudml.org/doc/204250.